# Python: Extract text from image with contours

Tags: python, pandas, ocr, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to extract the tables from the following image:

[Raw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8xHw.jpg)

I found a helpful algorithm to detect box-like structures in an image. This has helped to get this far:

[Original image with detected boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcPUK.jpg)

The code for detecting boxes in the image:

```
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd

path = '/Users/frederikspedtsberg/PycharmProjects/ML'


def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
                                        key=lambda b: b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)


# Functon for extracting the box
def box_extraction(img_for_box_extraction_path, cropped_dir_path):
    print("Reading image..")
    img = cv2.imread(img_for_box_extraction_path, 0)  # Read the image
    (thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255,
                                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Thresholding the image
    print(img_bin)
    img_bin = 255 - img_bin  # Invert the image

    print("Storing binary image to Images/Image_bin.jpg..")
    cv2.imwrite("Images/Image_bin.jpg", img_bin)

    print("Applying Morphological Operations..")
    # Defining a kernel length
    kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1] // 40

    # A verticle kernel of (1 X kernel_length), which will detect all the verticle lines from the image.
    verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))
    # A horizontal kernel of (kernel_length X 1), which will help to detect all the horizontal line from the image.
    hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))
    # A kernel of (3 X 3) ones.
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

    # Morphological operation to detect verticle lines from an image
    img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
    verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
    cv2.imwrite("verticle_lines.jpg", verticle_lines_img)

    # Morphological operation to detect horizontal lines from an image
    img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
    horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
    cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines.jpg", horizontal_lines_img)

    # Weighting parameters, this will decide the quantity of an image to be added to make a new image.
    alpha = 0.5
    beta = 1.0 - alpha
    # This function helps to add two image with specific weight parameter to get a third image as summation of two image.
    img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)
    img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
    (thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # For Debugging
    # Enable this line to see verticle and horizontal lines in the image which is used to find boxes
    print("Binary image which only contains boxes: Images/img_final_bin.jpg")
    cv2.imwrite("img_final_bin.jpg", img_final_bin)
    # Find contours for image, which will detect all the boxes
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
        img_final_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Sort all the contours by top to bottom.
    (contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")

    print("Output stored in Output directiory!")

    idx = 0
    for c in contours:
        # Returns the location and width,height for every contour
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # If the box height is greater then 20, widht is >80, then only save it as a box in "cropped/" folder.
        if (w > 80 and h > 20) and w > 3 * h:
            idx += 1
            new_img = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            cv2.imwrite(cropped_dir_path + str(idx) + '.png', new_img)

    # For Debugging
    # Enable this line to see all contours.
    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imwrite("img_contour.jpg", img)


box_extraction("Test3.jpg", cropped_dir_path=path)
```

Now I would like to hear if anyone knows what I should do from here in order to extract the data within the boxes and reorder it into a pandas data frame?

I understand that I could use pytesseract with lang = 'chi_sim' when I've found the particular box and then append it to a list. However, I cannot figure out how I access the boxes and neither do I understand how I should reshape the np array when I've gotten my list so that it fits an arbitrary picture.

All help is highly appreciated - Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `cv2` gives you image as `numpy.array` so you can use `arr[ row_start:row_end , column_start: column_end ]` to get part of image and use it with `pytesseract`. You already have `boundingRect` for this.

Comment: problem is to keep results in numpy array which rather is for tables which have cells with the same sizes - but you have cells which group rows or columns. maybe you will have to keep it in normal list or dictionary (or combination of both)